# .NET Client-Server shared objects

Tags: .net, client-server, shared-objects

I have a client-server setup where both make use of the same objects, but only the server is allowed to instantiate these object. The client can only make use of what it requests from the server. When the client requests a collection of lets say Foo objects. The server will create these, serialize them into Json and return them to the client. The client should then deserialize the Json into Foo objects.

I want to prevent the client from creating Foo objects since they're highly dependent on what is available at the server-side.

What is the best approach for this? I thought about creating two separate Foo classes; one for the client, one for the server. The client can only access the properties of the Foo class by its Getters and has no constructor defined. The server can create Foo objects and set it's properties through the constructor.

Maintainability will be an issue here, but also some duplicate code. The Foo objects are just plain model objects to hold information, nothing more.

Comment: Checkout the Remote Procedure Call features/examples in http://www.networkcomms.net. The way I understand your question this is exactly what you're after. I'm a developer for this library.